# Nodejs stream vs sendFile

Tags: node.js, express

I am testing on download speed both `res.sendFile(src);` and `fs.createReadStream(src).pipe(res);` and i don't see much difference. Which is better to serve files and why? If i will have huge files, stream will handle it better?

Comment: May I refer you to https://www.sitepoint.com/basics-node-js-streams/ to give you a better knowledge of what a stream in node actually is?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would opt for using `res.sendFile()`.

Ultimately, `res.sendFile()` pipes a stream to `res`, so in that regard they are basically the same.

However, `res.sendFile()` does some extra stuff, like setting the proper HTTP `Content-Type` header based on the filename, and because it uses the [`send`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/send) library under the hood it can (probably, I haven't tested this) handle partial responses and do content negotiation.

Comment: So if i keep using `res.sendFile()`, even on large files it will manage it great.

Comment: @GoncharDenys yes, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: How do you know that res.sendFile() pipes a stream to res? I haven't seen any reference to indicate that anywhere in the documentation. Could you please elaborate how you know?

Comment: @TalKohavy looking at the Express source :D But also, common sense: Express won't first read the entire file into memory before serving it.